# CUD buttons disappear in Fiori Elements app when adding @DefaultAggregation annotation to CDS view

Tags: sap-fiori

I've created a Fiori Elements List Report with CDS-BOPF-SADL and CRUD enabled (@ObjectModel.createEnabled: true, @ObjectModel.updateEnabled: true, @ObjectModel.deleteEnabled: true).

Everything is working fine but when I add the annotation "@DefaultAggregation: #SUM" to a CDS field
the CDS view becomes an analytical view, the table on the object page switches from responsive table to analytical table (as intended), but the buttons for the edit, create and delete operations disappear.

Does anyone know how to achieve CUD operations for analytical table with Fiori Elements standard?
Otherwise I will implement an extension for the CUD operations.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using two different CDS views and a "[QuickVariantSelection](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/5532c899e6e94137b18b8ee68df12efb)" in the UI to switch between analytical and standard/editable table view.